# Could someone explain where are the errors in this code in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to this site and also a newbee in vb.net, I created a simple form in vb.net, a form with 3 buttons, by clicking Button1 Species1.txt is created, and by clicking Button2 the lines in Species1.txt are copied in a String Array called astSpecies(), and by Button3 the String Array is copied in a new file, named Species2.txt, below is the code.

```
Public Class Form4
    Dim astSpecies() As String
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim myStreamWriter = New StreamWriter("C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\species1.txt", True)
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine("Pagasius pangasius")
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine("Meretrix lyrata")
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine("Psetta maxima")
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine("Nephrops norvegicus")
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine("Homarus americanus")
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine("Procambarus clarkii")
        myStreamWriter.Close()
        MsgBox("list complete")

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        Dim myStreamReader = New StreamReader("C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\species1.txt")
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim stOutput As String
        stOutput = ""

        Do While Not myStreamReader.EndOfStream
            astSpecies(i) = myStreamReader.ReadLine
            stOutput = stOutput & astSpecies(i) & vbNewLine
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        myStreamReader.Close()
        MsgBox(stOutput)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim myStreamWriter = New StreamWriter("C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\species2.txt", True)
        Dim o As Integer

        Do While o <= astSpecies.Length
            myStreamWriter.WriteLine(astSpecies(o))
            o = o + 1
        Loop
        myStreamWriter.Close()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Unfortunately your question isn't very clear.  What error(s) do you need help with?  Which line(s) give the errors?  (And update the question with this information, rather than replying as another comment.)

Comment: If I had to guess, though: seems you aren't initializing the string array `astSpecies` with a number of elements, so you are probably getting errors at lines with `astSpecies(i)`.  Perhaps a better way is to use a List: `Dim astSpecies As New List(Of String)`, then use `astSpecies.Add(myStreamReader.ReadLine)`.

Comment: No, you tell us where the errors are. You know what your code is supposed to do. You tell us exactly what you expect, exactly what you see and exactly where in the code this is happening. If you don't know those things then it's too soon to be posting a question here.

Comment: Also, why are you asking about multiple errors? Don't write big chunks of code and then look for multiple errors. Write your code in smaller chunks and make sure that each part is working before moving on the the next part. That is one way to isolate errors. When something breaks, you know that it is in the specific part that you added/changed most recently.

Comment: This code is so bizarre. You could do the whole lot with 3 lines: create an array, file.writealllines and file.copy. Seems like you don't even need the copy, just file.writealllines twice.  Is it an exercise in redundancy?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should make a few settings when it comes to VB.Net. 1.) set Option Strict to On 2.) remove the VB6 namespace. VB6 is the old Visual Basic. There are many functions in this that are inefficient from today's perspective. So please do not write `MsgBox()` but `MessageBox.Show("")`.

(If you still need control characters such as `NewLine` or `Tab`, you can set a selective reference with `Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.ControlChars`. Sounds contradictory, but it is useful, because why should you also write `ChrW(9)`, it is not legible.)

I quickly started a project myself and wrote whatever you wanted.
I still don't quite understand why you first write things into a text file, then read them out, and then write that into a second text file – I want to say: where do the strings originally come from? The strings must have been there already? Anyway, I filled a `List(of String)` in the `Button2_Click` procedure. This has the advantage that you don't have to know in advance how many strings are coming, and you can sort them later and so on ...

You should also discard all `Writer`s when you no longer need them. So use `Using`. Otherwise it can happen that the written files are not discarded and you can no longer edit the file.

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.ControlChars
Imports Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs
Public NotInheritable Class FormMain
    Private Path As String = ""
    Private allLines As New List(Of String)
    Private Sub FormMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(161, 181, 165)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Using OFolderD As New CommonOpenFileDialog
            OFolderD.Title = "Ordner auswählen"
            OFolderD.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
            OFolderD.IsFolderPicker = True
            If OFolderD.ShowDialog() = CommonFileDialogResult.Ok Then
                Path = OFolderD.FileName
            Else
                Return
            End If
        End Using

        Path &= "\Data.txt"
        Using txtfile As System.IO.StreamWriter = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(Path, True)
            txtfile.WriteLine("Pagasius pangasius")
            txtfile.WriteLine("Meretrix lyrata")
            txtfile.WriteLine("Psetta maxima")
            txtfile.WriteLine("Nephrops norvegicus")
            txtfile.WriteLine("Homarus americanus")
            txtfile.WriteLine("Procambarus clarkii")
            txtfile.Close()
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        'read all Text
        Dim RAT() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Path, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
        If RAT.Length = 0 OrElse RAT.Length = 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("The File only contains 0 or 1 characters.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand)
            Return
        End If

        allLines.AddRange(RAT)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim Pfad_txt As String = Path.Substring(0, Path.LastIndexOf("\"c)) & "\Data2.txt"
        Using txtfile As System.IO.StreamWriter = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(Pfad_txt, True)
            For Each Line As String In allLines
                txtfile.WriteLine(Line)
            Next
            txtfile.Close()
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

By the way: I use a FolderBrowserDialog in the `Button1_Click` procedure. This should be done so that the program also runs properly on other PCs. In order to be able to use the FBD, you have to download `Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs` in Visual Studio's own Nuget package manager.

[how to set Option Strict to On](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0M2VB.png)

[How to uncheck VB6.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wo5Yt.png)

[how to install FolderBrowserDialog in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RflN.png)

Comment: Tried unchecking Microsoft.VisualBasic, as you suggested and I only got a single bizarre compile error in my test code project. It involved a crypto package and MySql. The error disappears when I add back the VB check mark.

Comment: Dear Mary,
this is really bizarre. This check mark has an impact on around 15,000 VB6 items. It is possible that something in the other installed packages does not work then. **Edit:** `File.WriteAllText` belongs to `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO`. That's the issue.

Comment: `File.WriteAllText` can be found in System.IO https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=net-5.0 It is not part of the VB namespace.

Comment: and here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.writealltext?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Are you sure that IntelliSense took the System.IO Version?

Comment: I have one bit of code where Val comes in handy. It is a custom string sort that will take more code to avoid Val. Also some of the vb constants like vbTab are hard to do because we don't have the same escape characters as c sharp.

Comment: Only version of File.WriteAllText. Are you thinking of FileSystem.WriteAllText?

Comment: Yeah right, Val will be the problem. Yes, you would have to replace the function with a Vb.Net function. If you uncheck the checkbox at the beginning of a project, the IntelliSense will no longer suggest a VB6 method.
Perhaps I should add that I am active in a German forum that takes great care not to use an old VB6. Otherwise you will not be helped. That's why I pay so much attention to it.    Control characters are possible by setting a point reference `Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.ControlChars`.

Comment: I agree 100%. I am always harping on the use of the vb Strings class instead of the .net methods.

Comment: BTW, that crazy error disappeared when I remmed out the custom sort that used Val. Only time Val actually came in handy.

Comment: Surely Val has a viable modern equivalent for the context..

Answer (score 0):

Button1
If you want to use a `StreamWriter` it should be disposed. Classes in the .net Framework that have a `Dispose` method may use resources outside of the framework which need to be cleaned up. The classes shield you from these details by provided a `Dispose` method which must be called to properly do the clean up. Normally this is done with `Using` blocks.

I used a string builder which saves creating and throwing away a string each time you change the string. You may have heard that strings are immutable (cannot be changed). The `StringBuilder` class gets around this limitation. It is worth using if you have many changes to your string.

The `File` class is a .net class that you can use to read or write files. It is not as flexible as the stream classes but it is very easy to use.

Button 2
When you declared your `Array`, you declared an array with no elements. You cannot add elements to an array with no space for them. As Daniel pointed out, you can use the .net class `List(Of T)` The T stands for `Type`. This is very good suggestion when you don't know the number of elements in advance. I stuck with the array idea by assigning the array returned by `File.ReadAllLines` to the `lines` variable.

You get the same result by simply reading all the text and displaying it.

Button 3
Again I used the `File` class here which allows you to complete your task in a single line of code. Using 2 parameters for the `String.Join` method, the separator string and the array to join, we reproduce the original file.

```
Private SpeciesPath As String = "C:\Users\maryo\Documents\species1.txt"
Private lines As String()

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    sb.AppendLine("Pagasius pangasius")
    sb.AppendLine("Meretrix lyrata")
    sb.AppendLine("Psetta maxima")
    sb.AppendLine("Nephrops norvegicus")
    sb.AppendLine("Homarus americanus")
    sb.AppendLine("Procambarus clarkii")
    File.WriteAllText(SpeciesPath, sb.ToString)
    MsgBox("list complete")
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    lines = File.ReadAllLines(SpeciesPath)
    MessageBox.Show(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines))
    'OR
    MessageBox.Show(File.ReadAllText(SpeciesPath))
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    File.WriteAllLines("C:\Users\maryo\Documents\species2.txt", lines))
End Sub
```